# magento set base image if i have path to image

Tags: magento

```
$product1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'FN244403');
$product1ID = $product1->getId();
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "Select * from `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` WHERE `entity_id` = '$product1ID' 

LIMIT 1";
$rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
echo $path = $rows[0]['value'];
```

So, how i can now set Base, Small image, etc?
I am try do it, but this not help

```
try {
    $product1->setSmallImage($path)
        ->setThumbnail($path)
        ->setImage($path)
        ->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code for setting image.

```
$mediaAttribute = array (
            'thumbnail',
            'small_image',
            'image'
    );
```

`$product1->addImageToMediaGallery($filepath_to_image, $mediaAttribute, true, false);`